# What is the difference between engagement and promise?

Tags: meaning

If I have a previous appointment, what can I say instead of appointment? 
Previous engagement? Promise?
And I wonder exactly what they both mean.  (I thought they were similar.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the expression already discussed above, here are a few alternative expressions I tend to use in the situation:

- I already have plans for the evening(or day)
- I have prior committments for the afternoon

If you plan to use "promise" in a more informal manner, you could. But then you'd have to probably be more specific on what's keeping you occupied at the time.

For eg., I tend to say:

- I would love to, but I already promised to run an errand for my mom
- Ah - but I've promised my friend I'd volunteer for the charity event
  on friday.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "I already have plans" means that you would rather follw those plans than accept the invitation, while "I have a previous engagement" means that you can't get out of your previous commitment, much though you'd love to accept this one (which may be a white lie).

Answer (score 1):

*Previous engagement* is more correct. In this context, it refers to a specific time of promise: a promise to be at a particular place at a particular time.

*Promise* is a general commitment made by someone. You can promise not to eat someone else's lunch, for example, but you wouldn't refer to that kind of promise as *previous engagement*.

Answer (score 0):

The definition given for *promise* from the NOAD is the following:

> promise |ˈprɑməs|
>   noun
>   a declaration or assurance that one will do a particular thing or that guarantees that a particular thing will happen.
>    - *What happened to all those firm promises of support?*
>    - [with clause] *He took my fax number with the promise that he would send me a drawing.*
>    - [with infinitive] *I did not keep my promise to go home early*.
>   • the quality of potential excellence_: he showed great promise even as a junior officer.
>   • [in singular] an indication that something specified is expected or likely to occur: *the promise of peace*.

For *engagement* the definition is:

> engagement /ɪnˈgeɪdʒmənt/ /ɛnˈgeɪdʒmənt/
>   noun
>    1. a formal agreement to get married.
>   • the duration of such an agreement: *a good long engagement to give you time to be sure*.
>    2. an arrangement to do something or go somewhere at a fixed time: *a dinner engagement*.
>   • a period of paid employment.
>    3. the action of engaging or being engaged: *Britain's continued engagement in open trading*.
>    4. a fight or battle between armed forces.

*Promise* is not the correct word to replace *appointment* (the fact you went to an appointment doesn't implicate you did a promise to go); *engagement* is a better choice, but who listens could understand you are using the meaning 1 or 3.